# WordPress function to post ad after CSS

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, adsense

I have a WordPress website which has a page that shows the latest posts.Each post on the page is contained in the CSS class ".g1-collection-item".

I would like to have a function that places an adsense ad after every 5 times the class class is loaded.

Is there a function I could use to load data after every x amount of times a css class is rendered? Maybe a plugin could work. I tried WP-Quads but seem to have trouble placing the ad after x amount of featured posts.

Any sense of direction is greatly appreciated.

Comment: make your custom page using Visual composer, add a latest posts component and set the posts count to 5 then add an ads block using your ads plugin then posts with count 5 then ads and repeat
, I think you do not want the page to contain more than 5 ads

Comment: Thank you for the information. I am just about to implement this however, this will mess up my infinite scroll if I am not mistaken. Considering I will have to keep repeating the latest post element.

Comment: I think that you have to get rid off the infinite scroll because I think that you will not find such plugin, and coding this will be a strong pain, if I were you I will go with the option I told you, if you wish after repeating the ads enough time place a posts component that causes infinite scroll